# How can I get the latest revision date of my css file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, smarty

**Situation:**
My CSS was getting cached which was really annoying so I solved it this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.min.css?{$smarty.now}" type="text/css" />
```

But now it reloads it every single time, what I want now is to only reload when there are changes.

So, what I was thinking was instead of `{$smarty.now}` use something that gives me the latest revision date/time.

**Question:**
How do I get the latest revision date/time from my css file with php/smarty/javascript?

Comment: Add a global variable called version and on deploy increment it

Answer (score 0):

You could use php's [**`filemtime()`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filemtime.php). This function will get the last modification time of your file, which wouldn't change unless changes were made to the file.

You would do something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.min.css?{$filemtime("/css/screen.min.css")}" type="text/css" />
```

The [first forum item](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filemtime.php#81194) for this function in the documentation is a exact solution for your problem.